# DB2 Transaction Logs

Tags: java, c++, c, db2, ibm-midrange

How do I read the Transaction Logs of DB2 in iSeries / AS/400. Are there any C or C++ or Java APIs?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's a command to display the journal entries:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/cl/dspjrn.htm

And a number of API's for working with the journals:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/jc3.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here are pointers to information about the [format of log files](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0001910.html) and example [API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0001673.html) for accessing them. Unfortunately there aren't publicly available good examples available.

Comment: This is not applicable to DB2 on iSeries, which the OP uses.